# How to create stair effect

Tags: actionscript-3

So Im trying to constantly add elements on the stage and those elements to have a specific X and Y
what i mean and what i want to get is a stairway effect (up and down) :

lets say **1st** element is **100** pix above **stage.Y**

**2nd** element: **Y** is 1st element.y + 2nd element.height and its **X** position is 1st element.x + 2nd element.width(it appears immediately after we can see the whole body of 1st element)

**3rd** element : Y is 2st element.y + 3nd element.height and its X position is 2st element.x + 3nd element.width(it appears immediately after we can see the whole body of 2st element)

and the **last element before** the stairway effect goes down will be stage.stageheight - 100

like in this picture 
[image]

Yet I dont know how to do this (I know i have to put it in a for loop and in there to have a if statement that checks every time for the up and down border (stage.stageHeight - 100 and stage.Y + 100) but i cant figure it out)

what i have so far is this

```
private var itemsToAnimate:Array = []
    private var magnetBuff:Boolean = false;
    private var block:Block = new Block();

    private var stage_H:int = stage.stageHeight;
    private var block_H:int = block.height;


    public function AB_Main()
    {
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(evt:Event)
    {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEveryFrame);
    }

    private function onEveryFrame(ev:Event):void
    {
        createItems()
        animateItems();
    }

    private function animateItems():void
    {
        var itemToTrack:Block;

        for(var i:uint = 0; i < itemsToAnimate.length; i++)
        {
            itemToTrack = itemsToAnimate[i];
            itemToTrack.x -= 3;

            if(itemToTrack.x < -50)
            {
                itemsToAnimate.splice(i, 1);
                this.removeChild(itemToTrack);
            }
        }

    }


    private function createItems():void
    {
        if(Math.random() > 0.75)
        {
            var itemToTrack:Block = new Block();
            itemToTrack.x = stage.stageWidth - 50;
            itemToTrack.y = int( Math.random() * stage.stageHeight) 
            this.addChild(itemToTrack);
            itemsToAnimate.push(itemToTrack);
        }
    }
```

and that gets me a random positioning blocks like in the picture

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do something like this (writing it from my head without testing, I hope it will run ok):

```
function draw(min:Number, max:Number, horSpacing:Number, vertSpacing:Number):void {
    var increasing:Boolean = true;
    var lastY:Number = min + vertSpacing;
    for(var i:int=0; i<100; i++) {
        var c:Circle = new Circle(); //where Circle would be your dot with registration point in center
        c.x = 20 + i * horSpacing; //hardcoded margin
        c.y = (increasing) ? lastY - vertSpacing : lastY + vertSpacing;
        lastY = c.y;
        addChild(c);
        if(c.y <= max) increasing = false;
        if(c.y >= min) increasing = true;
    }
}

draw(stage.stageHeight - 100, 100, 20, 20);
```

Comment: yep it works ! when i put your **draw()** function in my **init()** function and then dell **createItems()**,but how do i constantly create Circles not like a exact  number (like here - 100 )

Comment: well i figured out that it might work this way even better, when i just add this **itemsToAnimate.push(c)** in the end of **draw()**, but how do i add additional Circles after all 100 are created already, because i cant do it in the **onEveryFrame()** cause that will create a **draw** function every frame

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is a value that will constantly increase along the x axis and then another that will either be increasing or decreasing along the y axis, alternating when you touch the top or bottom. That's as simple as:

```
var increaseY:Boolean = true;     // Whether we are moving up or down the y axis.
var position:Point = new Point(); // Position to place next item.
var move:int = 10;                // How much we move along each axis.
var margin:int = 100;             // Distance from top or bottom before alternating.

for each(var i:Sprite in itemsToAnimate)
{
    i.x = position.x;
    i.y = position.y;

    if(increaseY) position.y += move;
    else position.y -= move;

    position.x += move;

    if(position.y < margin || position.y > stage.stageHeight - margin)
    {
        // Reverse direction.
        increaseY = !increaseY;
    }
}
```

`move` can be adjusted to change the distance between each item along the path.

Comment: well i dont get where do i put this code exactly, because if i put it before i have anything in the **itemsToAnimate** it gets an error.
if i put it in the **animateItems()** it only makes 2 rows that at the top of the stage